# Calculate with datetime-format and integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm working with Python and SQL and for my work I have to calculate with a row departureTime in datetime format and a row *timeFromStart* in int format. The row timeFromStart is an integer that means minutes.

So for example: I have a departureTime like this: `2012-03-09 20:00:00.0000` and I have to add an 106 minutes to that. I just don't know how to do it. I've searched for it and found things like *addTime* and such but it didnt seem to work :(

Comment: What SQL service are you using? MS SQL, Postgres, MYSQL, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace GETDATE() with your date column name and also 106 with the required col name.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,106, GETDATE())
```